# Insert data into Redis using multithreading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, stackexchange.redis

I'm currently working with an assignment with stackexchange.Redis. It require the program to insert data into Redis using multithreading and I need to observe the efficiency of inserting data.For example, I random generate huge amount of string and start to insert them into Redis.

I have gone through some documentations and try to find similar questions from here but still don't know where I should start to modify the code to make it become multithreaded. Any idea where can I start?

```
    public static string RandomStringcha(int length)
    {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
          .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string randomstring = "";
        string value = "";
        var stringlist = new List<string>();

        for(int i=0; i <10000; i++)
        {
            randomstring =RandomStringcha(40);
            stringlist.Add(randomstring);
        }
       ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
        IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();

        foreach (var pair in stringlist)
        {
            value = pair;
            db.StringSet("mykey", value);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This is just an example. What if I random generate 10000 string and insert them into redis, here is where I need multithreading to test the insert speed. I just don't know where should i start.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with `Parallel.ForEach`. Does that give good enough performance?

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` might be 1 of my options. I will try to find the other way to test for better performance. By the way, thanks for realizing the `StringSet` problem.

Comment: Alternate options may involve seeing if there are async options available (`StringSetAsync` perhaps).